# Can't access my shared folder by ipv4, only ipv6 and name

Tags: windows-7

How to make possible to access to shared folder on win7 machine by ipv4? as my linux machine needs it.

The problem is in fact that i can't access by ipv4 to this folder even from this win7 computer, like `\\192.168.1.3\Shara`, only with name `\\Comp\Shara` or ipv6 `\\ipv6\shara`

Comment: Your Linux machine does *not* need it if you configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I would use its DNS name e.g `\\Comp\Shara`.

Or try changing the bind order of the NICs.

1. Go to:

   > Control Panel → Network and Internet → Network Connections
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>
3. Go to advanced
4. Then to advanced settings
5. At the bottom, select any entries for IPv4 and move them to the top.

Comment: yes I can, I even ping ::1 on win 7

Comment: there is n such a path "Control Panel → Network and Internet → Network Connections" on win7

Comment: I even made to prefer ipv4 over ipv6, still no result

Comment: found the answer - I need to enable client for microsoft networks

Comment: @LeyS Please post it as an answer using the "answer your question" button below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but Client for Microsoft Networks was already turned on. In my case, it was after a router update had turned on the Mesh network option (TP-Link router). Turning that off fixed it.